# Consulta con doble conexión a Base de datos - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo mi base de datos de usuarios y otra base de datos donde hago las consultas que necesito para ello construí dos conexiones una se llama `pgsql` y la otra `pgsql2`. El problema lo tengo cuando necesito hacer una consulta en la segunda bases de datos, por ejemplo:

```
$programs=DB::connection('pgsql2')->table('la_tabla')->where('usuario', 'el_usuario')->get();
```

Pero recibo el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "la_tabla" does not exist LINE 1: select * from "la_tabla" where "usuario" = $1 ^ (SQL: select * from "la_tabla" where "usuario" = el_usuario)
```

Sin embargo cuando utilizo el siguiente método `getPdo()` y lo imprimo en un `dd()` de esta manera:

```
$programs=DB::connection('pgsql2')->getPdo();
dd($programs);
```

Recibo un mensaje de conexión satisfactoria como se puede ver en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que es un error de principiante ya que estoy aprendiendo Laravel

Además dejo el codigo de mi Modelo Campaing

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Campaing extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'pgsql2';

    protected $table = 'la_tabla';
}
```

Editado:

**El problema lo estoy recibiendo porque a pesar de que estoy llamando a la segunda conexión donde tengo mi otra base de datos me esta es conectando a la primera y no entiendo por qué ya que las dos conexiones llaman a dos bases de datos distintas.**